# plpgsql return one row or another

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to look for data in two different ways in a function, and return as soon as I find a result.

First I want to run a query like;

`select * from company where company.id = x`

Then if that doesn't return results try a query like this

```
select company.*
  from
    company
  join
    company_alias on company.id = company_alias.company_id
  where
    company_alias.company_alias_id = x;
```

At the moment I'm doing this with a `union all`

```
create or replace function get_payer(x int) returns company as $$
  select * from company where company.id = x
  union all
  select company.*
  from
    company
  join
    company_alias on company.id = company_alias.company_id
  where
    company_alias.company_alias_id = x;
$$ language sql stable
set search_path from current;
```

This doesn't seem efficient, as I'm always running two queries. But I'm not sure how to structure a condition in a plpgsql function to handle this.

I've tried variations of the following without any luck

```
create or replace function payment_claim_payer(x int) returns company as $$
declare found_company company;
begin

  select * from company where company.id = x into found_company;

  if not exists found_company then
    select
      company.*
    from
      company
    join
      company_alias on company.id = company_alias.company_id
    where
      company_alias.company_alias_id = x into found_company;
  end if;

  return found_company;

end;
$$ language plpgsql stable
set search_path from current;
```

Comment: you want return `* ` or just `company_name/id`?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: that's the Oracle PL/SQL manual - that has nothing to do with Postgres' PL/pgSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last attempt was almost hit. You need a plpgsql (not sql) function and should examine the special variable [`found`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS):

```
create or replace function payment_claim_payer(x int) 
returns company language plpgsql as $$
declare found_company company;
begin
    select * 
    from company 
    where company.id = x 
    into found_company;

    if not found then
        select company.*
        from company
        join company_alias on company.id = company_alias.company_id
        where company_alias.company_alias_id = x 
        into found_company;
    end if;

    return found_company;
end;
$$;
```